# Swift extension of generic type that is Optional

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, binding, swift-extensions

I would like to extend SwiftUI Binding when its value is any optional type.
Is it possible

```
extension Binding where Value == Optional {
    func filter(_ predicate: @escaping (Value) -> Bool) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding<Value>(
            get: {
                if predicate(wrappedValue) { return nil }
                return wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                wrappedValue = $0
            }
        )
    }
}
```

It works if I use some concrete type like Error? But I want to have more general solution.

Comment: If `Value` is an optional for `predicate`, why isn't the return type (`Bool`) also optional? What would you do to convert an optional value to a non-optional boolean?

Comment: for value == nil it will return true as this values aren't filtered and are allowed by binding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a generic `T` where `T? == Value`. This means that `Value` is an optional (and `T` is the wrapped value of the optional, even though we don't need this type directly).

Code:

```
extension Binding {
    func filter<T>(_ predicate: @escaping (Value) -> Bool) -> Binding<Value> where T? == Value {
        Binding<Value>(
            get: {
                if predicate(wrappedValue) { return nil }
                return wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                wrappedValue = $0
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't use `T` type in your func

Comment: @Philip No, but that doesn't matter. You could effectively substitute the `Value`s for `T?`, but this is much cleaner, and also necessary because it tells the compiler that this method is _only_ available when `Value` is optional.